# SiteCore ECM attaching graphics in emails

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-ecm

Trying to get started with using ECM 1.3 on a site we have been using CMS 6.5 for about a year now. When building an HTML email to send out, I code the images just as I always have with our old mass email tool to point to published images on our SiteCore CD server (and I've tried including images through SiteCore ECM's own WYSIWYG editor), but when I send the email (either though test or dispatch to a test target audience) the jpeg images come through as attachments. I've read through the ECM documentation, done an incremental site publish before dispatching the message, searched here and the web at large to no avail. Anyone else come across this? Is it a problem with my Target Audience setup or is this just how ECM thinks emails should be sent?

THANKS!

Comment: Looks like you have tried most of the stuff, but can you please check "Base URL" - "http://localhost/" - The website address used for links in messages and for images, if they are hosted on the website. And secondly the "Embed Images" is true - Whether images are embedded in the message or links to images are inserted.

Comment: Thanks Shriroop. I dug through and found that the "Embed Images was set to true. this was not anywhere in the documentation from our implementation partner. Just needed that language to search on.

Comment: Glad the answer was of some help. So do you have any more issues outstanding?

Comment: Just answer your own question and accept the answer ;)!

Comment: @Shriroop looks like you've answered the question with your comments - why not make this an answer to the question, then anyone else viewing this question will see the answer straight away (you'll also get some lovely SO rep points as well ;-))

Comment: @mdresser thanks for the tip I have done so and waiting for user2946569 to accept it as an answer. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have tried most of the stuff, but can you please check:

1. **Base URL** - `http://localhost/` - *The website address used for links in messages and for images, if they are hosted on the website.*
2. **Embed Images** `is True` - *Whether images are embedded in the message or links to images are inserted.*

Hope this answer is of some help.